# 2D array lookup in swift - similar to vlookup in excel

Tags: arrays, swift, vlookup

Re:

[Finding a value in an array of arrays (similar to VLOOKUP function in Excel) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702404/finding-a-value-in-an-array-of-arrays-similar-to-vlookup-function-in-excel-in)

The above shows a method for determining the next lowest value in a 2D array given a search value. Reproduced here for convenience:

```
let testArray: [[Double]] = [
        [0,0],
        [1000,20.5],
        [3000,21],
        [3500,22.5],
        [3300,21],
]

let income: Double = 3500

var closest = testArray[0][0]
var closestDif = closest - income

for innerArray in testArray {
    let value = innerArray[0]

    let thisDif = value - income

    guard thisDif <= 0 else {
        continue
    }

    if closestDif < thisDif {
        closestDif = thisDif
        closest = value

        guard closestDif != 0 else {
            break
        }
    }
}

print(closest)
```

The value returned for closest is 3500. Can someone please describe how we then retrieve the corresponding second number in the array [3500, 22.5] i.e. 22.5?

(edit)
Is enumerated(){....} a cleaner way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily modify [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702920/4667835) from the linked Q&A to keep the whole inner array in `compactMap` and then find the maximum based on the first element of each inner array.

```
let result = testArray.compactMap { $0[0] <= income ? $0 : nil }.max(by: {$0.first! < $1.first!})! // [3500, 22.5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn’t really help me. Your answer gives sorted data in the first column, so I believe you are suggesting to also create a second column of sorted data? i.e. firstcolumn = [0, 1000, 3000, 3300, 3500] and secondcolumn = [0, 20.5, 21, 21, 22.5] <— is this correct? This works fine if the two sorted columns still have a correspondence to each other, but this may not always be the case. For example the last “row” in the 2D array above is [3300, 9]. In this case the 33000 and the 9 would end up in two different locations in the sorted firstcolumn and secondcolumn.

Comment: @klusmanp my bad, misunderstood your requirement. Check my updated answer, now it gives you the result you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

@David Pasztor thanks your solution works nicely. I’m working swift 3 so I had to substitute “flatMap” for "compactMap" but otherwise it works great and just one line of code! I have used the same technique to also obtain the nearest higher values in the data to the search value (income) and then interpolate to get a value in the second column proportional to the search value income. The interpolation requires guarding against divide by zero when the search value income equals one of the values in the first column in which case the corresponding result0[0],[1] and result1[0],[1] are identical.

```
let testarray:[[Double]] = [
    [0,0],
    [1000,20.5],
    [3000,21],
    [3500,22.5],
    [3300,21],
]

let income:Double = 3400
let result0 = testarray.flatMap { $0[0] <= income ? $0 : nil }.max(by: {$0.first! < $1.first!})!
let result1 = testarray.flatMap { $0[0] >= income ? $0 : nil }.min(by: {$0.first! < $1.first!})!

if income - result0[0] < 0.001 {
    let interp = result0[1]
    print(interp)
}
else {
    let interp = result0[1] + (result1[1] - result0[1])*(income -  result0[0])/(result1[0] - result0[0])
    print(interp)   // 21.75
}
```